# Copy zend project from one pc to another

Tags: php, zend-framework, dispatcher

I want to copy my zend project "InspectionSys" from one pc to another. I make the proper configuration of zend framework on the other pc, when I try to open my project through this URL

```
http://localhost/zendapps/InspectionSys/public/visits/visit/get_visits
```

this error occurs

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (zendapps) 
Request Parameters:

array (
'controller' => 'zendapps',
'action' => 'InspectionSys',
'public' => 'visits',
'visit' => 'get_visits',
'module' => 'default',
)
```

the mapping of the array options and the values are totally incorrect, what is the problem?
 **EDIT**

The mapping should be

```
array (
'module' => 'visits',
'controller' => 'visit',
'action' => 'get_visits',
'public' => 'public'


)
```

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa , See the edit section.

Comment: Set up `baseUrl` in the front controller; set it to `zendapps/InspectionSys/public`. You'll find details in the documentation.

Comment: @bububaba, it works, can you add your comment to the answers section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up `baseUrl` in the front controller; set it to `zendapps/InspectionSys/public`. You'll find details in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You should set a virtual host on your apache server. This is better than the solution proposed by bububaba .

Comment: +1 for the virtual host. It's always better to use it locally. This way your application will be ready for deployment in no time.